# Ninja Error While Building AOSP for Sony Devices

Tags: android, build, android-source, sony, ninja

I've been using [this](https://developer.sony.com/develop/open-devices/guides/aosp-build-instructions/build-aosp-nougat-7-1) guide in order to build AOSP Nougat 7.1.1. Using an Ubuntu Server 14.04 Virtual Machine using make -j4 I get the following error:

```
compile@androidcompile:~/android$ make -j4
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=7.1.1
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_arm
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.4.0-31-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=N6F27M
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
Running kati to generate build-aosp_arm.ninja...
$(shell cd libcore && ls -d */src/test/{java,resources} 2> /dev/null) was changed, regenerating...
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=7.1.1
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_arm
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.4.0-31-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=N6F27M
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
including ./abi/cpp/Android.mk ...
including ./art/Android.mk ...
including ./bionic/Android.mk ...
including ./bootable/recovery/Android.mk ...
including ./build/libs/host/Android.mk ...
including ./build/target/board/Android.mk ...
including ./build/target/product/security/Android.mk ...
including ./build/tools/Android.mk ...
including ./cts/Android.mk ...
FindEmulator: find: `cts/apps/CtsVerifier/src/android': No such file or directory
FindEmulator: find: `cts/hostsidetests/os/test-apps/HostLinkVerificationApp/src': No such file or directory
FindEmulator: find: `cts/libs/commonutil/src': No such file or directory
FindEmulator: cd: cts/tests/libcore/ojluni/resources: No such file or directory
FindEmulator: find: `cts/libs/commonutil/src': No such file or directory
including ./dalvik/Android.mk ...
including ./developers/samples/android/security/FingerprintDialog/Application/src/main/Android.mk ...
including ./development/apps/BluetoothDebug/Android.mk ...
including ./development/apps/BuildWidget/Android.mk ...
including ./development/apps/CustomLocale/Android.mk ...
including ./development/apps/Development/Android.mk ...
.
.
.
including ./vendor/oss/transpower/Android.mk ...
including ./vendor/qcom/opensource/dataservices/Android.mk ...
including ./vendor/qcom/opensource/fm/Android.mk ...
including ./vendor/qcom/opensource/location/loc_api/Android.mk ...
including ./vendor/qcom/opensource/time-services/Android.mk ...
Starting build with ninja
ninja: Entering directory `.'
ninja: error: 'device/generic/goldfish/fstab.goldfish', needed by 'out/target/product/generic/root/fstab.goldfish', missing and no known rule to make it
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1

#### make failed to build some targets (02:26 (mm:ss)) ####
```

I would love if someone could help me fix this issue I've been trying to fix it myself for 5 days and I still haven't found the solution to it.
Thanks in advance!